# How do I make a div element stay on a same position as before after page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/4gfqnyas/ there is a pure java script function that will move the  div `<div id="btn"></div>` to either left or right (and also change the forms) when either Login or Register button is clicked.

How do I make the div stay in the exact same position as I left, after each reload (or after clicking on the register **submit** button). I don't want the div to reset back to Login position after reload(or after clicking on the register **submit** button).

For example: Let's say I click on Register, the div will move to the register and the form will also change to register. Now when I click on Register **submit** button, the div automatically goes to login and so does the form which makes it impossible for me to display any errors in the register form if the user entered invalid information. I want it to stay on the same form after a reload or after clicking the respective **submit** buttons.

Comment: you can just add a query param or a hash tag depending on which screen you are showing and read it from url and change accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you can use `localStorage`.

Note that some super old browser don't support `localStorage`, but that is not a big thing, almost nobody has them.

Let me know if it works. :)

Here is a fixed version (CSS stays the same) :

HTML :

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="form-box">
        <div class="button-box">
            <div id="btn"></div>
                <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="toggle-btn" onclick="login()">Login</button> 
                <button type="button" id="registerButton" class="toggle-btn" onclick="register()">Register</button>
        </div>
        <div class="social-icons">
            <img src="images/fb.png">
            <img src="images/gp.png">
            <img src="images/tw.png">
        </div>
        
        <form method="POST" action="val_log.php" id="login" class="input-group">
            <input name="Lname" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User ID" minlength="4" maxlength="15">
            <input name="Lpassword" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" minlength="5" maxlength="60">
            <input name="Lrempass" type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span> Remember Password</span>
            <button name="Lsubmit" type="submit" class="submit-btn"> Login </button> 
        </form>
        <form method="POST" action="val_reg.php" id="register" class="input-group">
            <input name="Rmail" type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email ID" >
            <input name="Rname" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User ID" minlength="4" maxlength="15">
            <input name="Rpassword" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" minlength="5" maxlength="60">
            <input name="REpassword" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" maxlength="60">
            <input name="Rterms" value="selected" type="checkbox" class="check-box" ><span> I agree to the terms & conditions</span>
            <button name="Rsubmit" type="submit" class="submit-btn" > Register  </button>
        </form>
    </div>        
</div>
```

JS :

```
var x = document.getElementById("login");
var y = document.getElementById("register");
var z = document.getElementById("btn");

console.log(x)
    
function register(){
    x.style.left = "-400px";
    y.style.left = "50px";
    z.style.left = "110px";
}
function login(){
    x.style.left = "50px";
    y.style.left = "450px";
    z.style.left = "0";
}


// Added code


if(localStorage){

    if(localStorage.getItem('rememberButtonChoice')){

        let getChoice = localStorage.getItem('rememberButtonChoice');

        if(getChoice == "loginChoice"){

        login();

    }

    else{

        register();

        }

    }

}



let loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton');

let registerButton = document.getElementById('registerButton');



loginButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if(localStorage){

        localStorage.setItem("rememberButtonChoice", 'loginChoice');

    }

});


registerButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if(localStorage){

        localStorage.setItem("rememberButtonChoice", 'registerChoice');

    }

});
```

Comment: If localstorage is not avalaible, you may use a cookie and destroy it later.

Comment: Anything you need :)

Answer (score 0):

When your page reload it loose all the data and set itself to default initialize data. You can make use of localStorage for keeping track of what you have clicked. Something similar to below example.

And you said you want to display error on page reload so in the first place why you want to reload . You can show them without reloading the page as well and if you are using server side form submission than you can use url query params to maintain the click history.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("login");
    var y = document.getElementById("register");
    var z = document.getElementById("btn");
        
    function register(){
        x.style.left = "-400px";
        y.style.left = "50px";
        z.style.left = "110px";
        window.localStorage.setItem("cur_page", "register");
    }
    function login(){
        x.style.left = "50px";
        y.style.left = "450px";
        z.style.left = "0";
        window.localStorage.setItem("cur_page", "login");
    }
    
    const cur_page = window.localStorage.getItem("cur_page");
    
    switch (cur_page) {
      case "login":
        login();
        break;
      case "register":
        register();
        break;
      default:
        login();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks both the solution(your one and the above one) worked well.